# When upgrading from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4, why does rake give 'uninitialized constant ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently attempting to upgrade a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4. I updated my `Gemfile` by referencing the correct version of Rails:

```
gem 'rails', '~>4.0.0'
```

as well as removing the `assets` header, per [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile).

Next, I attempted to run `rake rails:update`. It gave me this error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:6:in `<module:AttributeAssignment>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:3:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:300:in `<class:Base>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:281:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:38:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `instance_exec'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb:253:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb:253:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `load_tasks'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/vagrant/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place I could find this error online was [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1443).

I searched for `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` on that page, and found it [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1443#issuecomment-17132073).

As I was reading that comment and following, I found [this one](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1443#issuecomment-17160532), which said:

> Rails 3.2 apps can just add strong_parameter gem AFAIK and it would work out of the box.

Looking at my `Gemfile` again I realized what the problem was. It contained this line:

```
gem 'strong_parameters'
```

The problem is that the `strong_parameters` gem **duplicates** the Rails 4 way of doing things, allowing newer, better code to be used in Rails 3.2. Thus, it conflicts with the built-in functionality in Rails 4.

I removed that line from my Gemfile, and after running `bundle`, the `rake` command worked.

**Edit:** After restarting `unicorn`, I was getting a similar error in the log. I deleted `config/initializers/strong_parameters.rb`, but that didn't seem to help. However, after rebooting my VM, it was working properly.